# Difference between *FILE and *STMF elements oa a AS/400 ftp server

Tags: ftp, ibm-midrange, apache-commons-net

I was trying to download files from an AS/400 ftp server using the apache FTPClient and it should work because the library correctly uses a OS400FTPEntryParser to parse the response from the server.

However this specific parser marks as valid files only the elements available on the ftp server  having the file type set to *STMF while all my elements are flagged as *FILE on the ftp server and then marked as unknown type when parsed by the apache FTPClient. Also associated to every *FILE element I have a correspondent *MEM element that includes the file extension.

Before writing my own parser i'd like to undertand the difference between these two types and if there is a valid reason to mar these files as unknown.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure it's `*MEM` and not `*MBR`?

`*STMF` are stream files in the integrated file system.  They are identical to the PC definition of a file.

`*FILE` objects are database tables and `*MBR` are named partitions within the table.  Every `*FILE` has at least one `*MBR`.

The midrange and mainframe systems are unique in that you can actually retrieve the contents from a database table using FTP.  The data is returned in a fixed length format.

For more information:

[FTP - File systems and naming conventions](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzaiq/rzaiqftpconvn.htm)

Comment: That is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for; even though I do have *MEM and not *MBR this explains the behavior I've been experiencing. I have only a doubt left: why when I upload a file via ftp it is automatically created as *FILE and can this be configured otherwise?

Comment: @genjosanzo That means you are in a library filesystem (database) instead of the stream (ifs) filesystem.  The normal way to move to the IFS is to issue an immediate `cd` after logging in.  Alternately you can issue the `QUOTE SITE NA 1` command followed by `cd` to move to the IFS filesystem.

Comment: @genjosanzo I fixed the reference link.  It should provide a lot more details to explain the process.

Comment: It should be noted that the "library filesystem" is in the IFS (Integrated File System) just like all other file systems are. The distinction should be "library filesystem" vs. "/root filesystem" (or some other non-library filesystem such as /QOpenSys or /QDLS). Also, the NAMEFMT 1 FTP command doesn't switch "to the IFS filesystem" but rather "to the IFS **naming** format". The library filesystem (/QSYS.LIB) is just as accessible under NAMEFMT 1 as it is under NAMEFMT 0. A database *FILE object is viewed as a single-level directory with *MEM objects in IFS naming format.